# Audio Recording in React Native and sending audio in stream

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am currently working on an app that required me to use react-native-audio-recorder-player.
So far it has been working great as i am able to record audios and send them to the backend to be transcribed by OpenAI's whisper API, but as you know we would have to wait for users to complete the recording and then send it to backend as form data. So, to counter this i want to send audio as it is being recorded as data stream is there a way it is possible using react-native-audio-recorder-player or if you can guide me in a direction on how to implement this, it'll help me a lot.
I have also tried using react-native-audio-react which provides an event listener that returns encoded base 64 data chunks. I have tried to concatenate and convert into audio, also tries making blob but nothing seems to work.
I hope i can find help here.

I have tried searching for other means with no returns.